# Laravel Nova Impersonation - Redirects to / would like to redirect to backend

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm using the new (as of writing this) Laravel Nova 4.0 and the official [impersonation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/customization/impersonation.html) trait / implementation.

When I impersonate a user it redirects to the frontend homepage `/`. I would like it to redirect to `/admin` in general. If I can achieve this, I'd really like to have more granular control which users (based on a simple user `type`) go to which route by default.

I can't find anything in the documentation, looking through the code or other questions asked in Nova threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config/nova.php` has options as to which URLs you can use when starting/stopping impersonation:

```php
    'impersonation' => [
        // NOTE: change this from the default '/'
        'started' => '/admin',
        'stopped' => '/',
    ],
```

Because this is loaded as a config file, it's potentially worth noting that you can't use named routes here as the configuration will be bootstrapped in before the routes are defined.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Is this in the documentation? I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: @Grant Nothing in the docs yet, was in the [v4.14.0 release notes](https://nova.laravel.com/releases/4.14.0) then just diving into the config/source updates to see what changed.